# Javascript Multi-level Nested Quotes

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, escaping, quotes

I'm doing some work w/ the JQWidgets grid which requires replacing the value in a column w/ an image. To do this, I need to return a string to the cellsrenderer. In addition, clicking on the icon will perform a Javascript function call, passing several parameters. One of the parameters is a string value, and I'm having difficulty setting up my return string.

The Javascript function I'm calling takes 4 variables - three integers and a string. This is the code for the return:

```
return "<span style='margin:4px; display:block;'><a href='javascript:;' onclick='unenroll(" + courseID + ", \"courseName\", " + progress + ", " + userID + ")' class='delete-icon' title='<cfoutput>#APPLICATION.LC.getValue("UnassignFrom")#</cfoutput> ' + courseName + '?'><cfoutput>#APPLICATION.LC.getValue("UnassignFrom")#</cfoutput> ' + courseName + '?</a></span>";
```

courseID, courseName, progress and userID are all Javascript variables; courseName is a string.

As you can see, I've tried escaping the quotes around the courseName w/ slashes, which doesn't work. Neither does encoding Unicode or HTML-entity versions of quotes. I've even tried switching around all the quotes (ie. from single to double and double to single), but still nothing.

**Edit -** this is what I'm getting back from Firebug: syntax error 
unenroll(2333, "Exam Automation", 50, )

Comment: Escaping the quotes with backslashes does work. What exactly is the problem?  What does the HTML look like (via Firebug or another browser developer tool) after the code runs?

Comment: Also, if that's JavaScript code, then that embedded Coldfusion call doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: The Coldfusion call is part of our translation system - we pass a key value to the language controller (LC), which returns the text in the selected language. It complicates my example, but I left it in in case it was affecting the call.

Comment: @Pointy I've added the Firebug info to the question.

Comment: Well it looks like "userID" is empty; there's a comma but no final parameter.

Comment: Wow, I was so focused on the quote issue I didn't even register when the error changed. Thanks for the extra set of eyes Pointy.

Answer (score 1):

you just missed some of escaping quotes near "UnassignFrom", here is the correct version:

```
return "<span style='margin:4px; display:block;'><a href='javascript:;' onclick='unenroll(" + courseID + ", \"courseName\", " + progress + ", " + userID + ")' class='delete-icon' title='<cfoutput>#APPLICATION.LC.getValue(\"UnassignFrom\")#</cfoutput> ' + courseName + '?'><cfoutput>#APPLICATION.LC.getValue(\"UnassignFrom\")#</cfoutput> ' + courseName + '?</a></span>"
```

Comment: Since that section is inside the cfoutput tags, it actually doesn't need to be escaped. Thanks though.

Comment: sorry, I'm not familiar with coldfusion :)